# Make subfolder refer to different hosting environment

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, url

The situation we're finding ourselves in is:

### Webhost #1

Serves `www.example.com`

### Webhost #2

Serves `www.widget.com`

For various technical reasons, we are unable to unify the sites into a single host.  What we'd like to do, is make:

www.example.com/widget

Serve `Webhost #2's` content (dropping the domain www.widget.com).  Ideally, making `example.com/widget` have a CNAME record point to `#2's` IP would be ideal, but I know this is not possible.

Are we able to make a subfolder in a URL point to another host without redirecting to subdomains?  We need the URL structure to remain natural (no subdomains).

Proxy's are not an option, as the two environments are geographically very far apart.  (Again, for a variety of technical reasons).

Answer (score 0):

Just put a redirect on www.widget.com to www.example.com/widget.

Drop you widget.com content in the example.com/widget folder on the web server and you should be fine. If you have absolute paths in the widget web content, you will need to update them to be relative paths pointing to /widget.

After some time passes, you can kill the redirect on the one widget.com.

Both apache and IIS make redirects pretty seamless.

Also, if you update the DNA entry for www.widget.com to point to the same IP as example.com, you can tell your webserver to look at the host header and if the host header matches www.widget.com redirect to example.com/widget.

In apache you would setup a virtual host with a redirect, in IIS, you would setup a blank site with host defined in the binding and set the redirect in the site settings.

Comment: I can't just drop content on widget.com to a folder on example.com/widget, they are both completely different hosting environments and applications (one is on a dedicated server in USA, the other is in a scaleset on Azure in Europe).

Comment: @TomGullen what is the platform for example.com?

Comment: Example.com is an ASP.net app running on IIS7.  Widget.com is a scalable Azure ASP.net app running in the cloud.  Ideally, I'd like to simply point the CNAME record for www.example.com/widget to Azure, but of course this is not possible with the way DNS works.  Am wondering if there's another way (I don't think there is) without using proxies.